# Save content of HTML in local storage

Tags: java, javascript, xml

i want to fetch xml file from the links like

http://api.worldbank.org/countries/GBR/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?date=2004:2012

it returns a xml file, i don't know how to save this file in my folder named "temp" using java or javascripts, actually i don't want to display this result of that link to the user, I'm generating such links dynamically.

please help!!!

Comment: What is your client application written in? HTML5 or Java?

Comment: it has been written in Java(struts2), i tried JavaScript but problem is that it needs a user intervention, i dnt need user in between

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend you to use an HTML parser library like jsoup in this situation. Please have a look at the below steps for better under standing:

```
1. Download jsoup core library  (jsoup-1.6.1.jar) from http://jsoup.org/download
2. Add the jsoup-1.6.1.jar file to your classpath.
3. Try the below code to save the xml file from the URL.

package com.overflow.stack;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

/**
 *
 * @author sarath_sivan
 */
public class XmlExtractor {

    public static StringBuilder fetchXmlContent(String url) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder xmlContent = new StringBuilder();
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        xmlContent.append(document.body().html());
        return xmlContent;
    }

    public static void saveXmlFile(StringBuilder xmlContent, String saveLocation) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(saveLocation);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(xmlContent.toString());
        bufferedWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Downloading completed successfully..!");
    }

    public static void downloadXml() throws IOException {
        String url = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/GBR/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?date=2004:2012";
        String saveLocation = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"sarath.xml";
        XmlExtractor.saveXmlFile(XmlExtractor.fetchXmlContent(url), saveLocation);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        XmlExtractor.downloadXml();
    }

}

4. Once the above code is executed successfully, a file named "sarath.xml" should be there in your temp folder.
```

Thank you!

Comment: by the way, what is the use of jsoup and where the file sarath.xml is stored, i'm not finding that file.

Comment: Consider the two statements in the above code:                                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
xmlContent.append(document.body().html());                          Here we are using jsoup to connect to the URL and to download the HTML source from the connected URL. Since the xml file is inside the HTML <body> of your URL, we can use document.body().html() to extract the XML contents from the body.

Comment: And the "sarath.xml" file will be created in your system's temp folder. You can verify this by following the below steps:            1. Press Windows button + r from your keyboard to get the run prompt.                                                              2. Type %temp% in the run prompt and press ENTER button.              3. Now you will see all the files inside your temp folder.           4. Check whether the "sarath.xml" file is there or not.                 It should be there!!

Comment: hey sarath can we change this "java.io.tmpdir" to any other directory, can we directly give a directory location here?

Comment: Obviously you can do that. System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") is for getting the temp folder of your computer system. If you would like to save the xml file to any other location, you can give the path directly. Example: String saveLocation = "D:/your-folder-name/sarath.xml".

Comment: can we extend this logic to Struts2, I wrote the function call inside the execute() of a class QueryBuilder which extends ActionSupport, the problem is that i need to give location inside the file system (of server say "FILES"), i tried relative path but its not saving it in that particular folder, can u help me with this problem, when i execute that as a java application then it executes absolutely fine.

Comment: You can call the XmlExtractor.saveXmlFile(XmlExtractor.fetchXmlContent(url), saveLocation) method inside the execute() method of a class, QueryBuilder which extends ActionSupport as I shown below

Comment: yeah, i did that, but by simply adding / as a location it is saving file in the location where my eclipse is working+

Answer (score 0):

Well your body is XML not HTML, just retrieve it using Apache HttpClient, and pump the read InputStream to a FileOutputStream. What was the problem? Do you want to save parsed content in a formatted form?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String execute() {
        try {
            String url = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/GBR/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?date=2004:2012";
            String saveLocation = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"sarath.xml";
            XmlExtractor.saveXmlFile(XmlExtractor.fetchXmlContent(url), saveLocation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: i dnt want it to save in temp dir of the system, i want it to save in server, it is going to client side...